# Variable size in c++

Tags: c++, variables, memory-management

I am writing a cuda C program. So, in order to put each variable in the appropriate  memory, I am looking for a tool that can give me the memory size of a c++ variable,  object, structure...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(my_type)` will give you the size of `my_type` in bytes